# local variable 'old' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm A Python Beginner. I'm trying to create an age calculator with Python Tkinter...
and I'm facing the error. ("Local variable 'old' referenced before assignment")

MY CODE:

```
from tkinter import*

window = Tk()

window.geometry("400x500")
window.title('Age Calculator')

def calculate():

    TEXT = 2021-int(taker.get())
    AGE = Label(window, text='Your Age Is: ' + str(TEXT), font = ('impact', 25), bg='red')
    AGE.place(x=90, y=370)

    if TEXT <= 12 and TEXT > -1:

        old.place(x=78, y=418)
        taker.delete(0, END)
    elif TEXT > 12 and TEXT < 19:
        old.place(x=55, y=418)
        taker.delete(0, END)

    elif TEXT > 18 and TEXT < 60:
        old.config(text='TEST1')
        old.place(x=69, y=418)
        

    elif TEXT >= 60:
        old = Label(window, text='You Are OLD!', font=('impact', 25), bg='pink')
        old.place(x=104, y=418)


old = Label(window, text='TEST2', font=('impact', 25), bg='pink')
old.place(x=69, y=418)


canvas.create_rectangle(500, 200, 0, 500, fill='#e3e17d')
```

Comment: You need to declare `global old` inside `calculate()`.

Comment: It is better to call `old.config(...)` instead of assigning `old` to a new instance of `Label` inside `calculate()`.

Comment: Either `calculate` must not be a function, or you need to create a class with a `self.old` or you need to parse `old` through your calculate variable. Also, try to avoid creating global variables where possible.

Comment: Statement `old = Label(window, text='You Are OLD!', font=('impact', 25), bg='pink')` in function, then `old` will be local variable if `old` not declared as global variable in function. You will get exception `UnboundLocalError` if another statement called first, like `old.place(x=78, y=418)`.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I declared global old and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*

window = Tk()

window.geometry("400x500")
window.title('Age Calculator')

def calculate():
    global old
    TEXT = 2021-int(taker.get())
    AGE = Label(window, text='Your Age Is: ' + str(TEXT), font = ('impact', 25), bg='red')
    AGE.place(x=90, y=370)

    if TEXT <= 12 and TEXT > -1:
        old.place(x=78, y=418)
        taker.delete(0, END)
    elif TEXT > 12 and TEXT < 19:
        old.place(x=55, y=418)
        taker.delete(0, END)

    elif TEXT > 18 and TEXT < 60:
        old.config(text='TEST1')
        old.place(x=69, y=418)
        

    elif TEXT >= 60:
        old = Label(window, text='You Are OLD!', font=('impact', 25), bg='pink')
        old.place(x=104, y=418)


old = Label(window, text='TEST2', font=('impact', 25), bg='pink')
old.place(x=69, y=418)


canvas.create_rectangle(500, 200, 0, 500, fill='#e3e17d')
```

global means that the variable can be referenced